# SecurityFilterChain Method Spring Boot 3.1.5 Kotlin

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-security

I am trying to create a securityFilterChain method with Spring Boot 3.1.5

Here is what I have:

```
@Bean
@Throws(java.lang.Exception::class)
fun securityFilterChain(http: HttpSecurity): SecurityFilterChain? {
    http
        .authorizeHttpRequests(
            Customizer<AuthorizationManagerRequestMatcherRegistry> { authorizeHttpRequests: AuthorizationManagerRequestMatcherRegistry ->
                authorizeHttpRequests
                    .requestMatchers("/**").hasRole("USER")
            }
        )
    return http.build()
}
```

Unfortunately I get this compilation error:
"Type arguments should be specified for an outer class. Use full class name to specify them."

Can anyone please guide in the right direction ?

Here is what else I have I tried:

```
@Bean
@Throws(Exception::class)
     fun filterChain(http: HttpSecurity): SecurityFilterChain {
         http.authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests
        .requestMatchers("/users/registration").permitAll())
        return http.build()
     }
```

but that does not compile as well.

Here are the project dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation("org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("org.springframework.security:spring-security-core")
    implementation("org.springframework.security:spring-security-config")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    implementation("io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt:0.9.0")
    implementation("org.postgresql:postgresql")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test") {
         exclude(group = "org.junit.vintage", module = "junit-vintage-engine")
    }
    testImplementation("org.springframework.security:spring-security-test")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation includes an overview of [Kotlin Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/configuration/kotlin.html#kotlin-config-httpsecurity):

> ```
> import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.invoke
>
> @Bean
> open fun filterChain(http: HttpSecurity): SecurityFilterChain {
>   http {
>     authorizeRequests {
>       authorize(anyRequest, authenticated)
>     }
>     formLogin { }
>     httpBasic { }
>   }
>   return http.build()
> }
> ```

This example uses the Kotlin DSL and includes an import to the `invoke` extension function for `HttpSecurity` which is required to use the DSL in this way.

---

Also note that this example uses `authorizeRequests` but it is recommended to use `authorizeHttpRequests`. I've [filed an issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/14384) to improve this snippet in the docs.